# autonomous database in two regions

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-19c

**Backgroup on the autonomous database**
For the last couple of years Oracle have offered a "autonomous" or "self driving" database in their cloud which is only available on the Oracle cloud.  If you cannot guess from the name its a PaaS/SaaS type of operation where a lot of routine tasks - from performance tuning to making database backups are automated.  It generally does a decent job too.  Its Oracle flagship RDMS database and they are actively trying to push all their customers onto it.

My question is what is the best approach to setting up an autonomous database that can be used in two regions.  I would like to have databases in regions local to customers on different continents.  Its not urgent right now but I think will become necessary and I should getting an understand of this.

Is it possible/practical to set up two databases and somehow keep them in sync?  Are there any best practices around this that I should be aware of?  Any options that don't involve paying oracle would be ideal!

Comment: Please edit your post and describe the "autonomous database". Not many people know what your mean. (hint: it's Oracle Cloud offering for their flagship RDBMS).  Are you on the free tier?  Also, you should still tag your post with the Oracle version that your database is running.

Comment: Thanks I'll briefly I'll clarify what is the autonomous database - but if people don't know what it is I don't think they will be able to answer!  BTW an autonomous database will always be a recent version of the database.

Comment: 1) ATP Free Tier was upgraded from 18c to 19c last week.  IIRC - you can still choose (to some degree) what version of DB you are running. Always tag your question with RDBMS version 2) The answer should be the same whether you run on your own hardware or in the cloud (ATP). Anyone with Oracle RDBMS EE knowledge will be able to give you a legitimate answer (single sharded DB).  The difference in the implementation is who you talk with to get it done.  Your IT folks or your Oracle Cloud Sales Rep.